# How to delete data from a XLSX file while keeping formatting in R

Tags: r, excel

I have 3 xlsx files with 7 sheets each. Each morning I have to delete the contents of each sheet to prepare for importing new data.

I want to automate the process using R. I can do this with Excel Macro, but an R script is what I want (that way I don't need to wait longer as macro enabled files are way slower).

I only want to get blank sheets while keeping the sheetnames, and all formatting (I have formatted all cells as Text, and cells have particular widths). Solutions using `openxlsx` package are more appreciated.

EDIT:

The sheets contain about 15 columns and at max 200 rows. Still non vectorized solutions are a bit slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bit of a hack,  but you can simply write an empty string to each cell that is in use and then save the resulting workbook.

```
library(openxlsx)
wb = loadWorkbook("Test.xlsx")

for(ss in 1:length(wb$worksheets)) {
    Rows = wb$worksheets[[ss]]$sheet_data$rows
    Cols = wb$worksheets[[ss]]$sheet_data$cols

    for(i in 1:length(Rows)) {
        writeData(wb,ss,"",  startCol = Cols[i], startRow = Rows[i])
    }
}
saveWorkbook(wb, "Test2.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

However,  Why can't you just make the empty spreadsheet once as a template and then make a copy it every time you need to use it?

Comment: Actually this is something I want to try to see if I can do it this way. Templates might be a good idea to reduce the pains for now.

Comment: BTW, I find writing `NULL` to each cell instead of `""` actually speeds up the execution by a factor of 100-150!

Comment: Thanks for the tip about NULL.  I will give that a  try.

Comment: I am looking to vectorize your solution, will try that tomorrow. For now, it is working beautifully. Thank you.

Comment: I will be glad if it saves you some time or trouble.

Comment: Just understood the best option. Make templates, and then paste it thrice with the names provided... I looked for an overcomplicated solution. Thank you, it was your suggestion. :) BTW, I vectorized it...

Answer (score 3):

You can use deleteData function of openxlsx.

```
library(openxlsx)
wkbook <- loadWorkbook(file = "test.xlsx")
deleteData(wkbook , sheet = 1,cols = 1:100, rows = 1:100000, gridExpand = TRUE)
```

After deletion use you use WriteData function to insert/append data to existing file. Here I'm clearing rows till 100000 and columns till 100. You can identify the last row and last column of the workbook and delete accordingly.